# Elegant way to access jQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have HTLM like this:

```
<ul id="citylist">
  <li>Seoul</li>
  <li>Brisbane</li>
  <li>Busan</li>
</ul>
```

If I want to bind a click event to `<li>` elements, I would write JavaScript like this:

```
var $cityList = $('#citylist');

$cityList.delegate('li', 'click', function() {
  //.. I want to access to $cityList
});
```

If I want to access to selector from inside handler function, is there any elegant way to access to `$cityList` without using `$cityList`?

**Update**

I made some mistake while making example. I had to bind events to `<li>`.

Comment: have you tried with `$(this)` ? Or do you need the selector String?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you absolutely don't want to access `$cityList` you can use [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```
var $cityList = $('#citylist');

$cityList.delegate('li', 'click', function() {
  console.log($(this).closest('#citylist'));
});
```

Or you can wrap the callback like this (and pass `$citylist`):

```
var $cityList = $('#citylist');

$cityList.delegate('li', 'click', (function (parent) {
  return function () {
    // parent will be $citylist, this will be the li
    console.log(arguments, evt, this, parent);
  };
})($cityList));
```

Answer (score 0):

Beware that you're not binding `click()` to `li` elements, but to the `ul` element.

This binds to the `li` elements:

```
$('#citylist li').click(function() {
    // code here
});
```

If you want to just bind direct descendants of `#citylist` use this:

```
$('#citylist > li').click(function() {
    // code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

javascript has closures so if you do this:

```
var $cityList = $('#citylist');

$cityList.children().click(function() {
  // you can already access $cityList like this:
  $cityList.myFunction();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this through modifying handler's context

```
var $cityList = $('#citylist');

$cityList.delegate('li', 'click', $.proxy(function(event) {
    console.log(event.currentTarget, this.parentObj, this.parentObj.selector);
}, $.extend(this, {
    parentObj: $cityList
})));
```

Example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yMFur/2/)

Answer (score -1):

```
var $cityList = $('#citylist');

$cityList.find('li').click(function() {
   // click event handler
});
```

you can absolutely and more efficiently use $cityList in the handler function.

Comment: Wait. What? Bind click on click?

Comment: you want to use `.children` in place of `.find`, or you'll bind to any nested `li` elements as well.

Answer (score -1):

I think one of the best ways to bind what you want and use the selector you are looking for is:

```
$('li', 'ul#citylist').bind('click', function()
{
    if($(this).parent().is('ul#citylist')) alert('I am #citylist!');
});
```

With $('li', 'ul#citylist') you are telling jQuery the element you want to select and its parent, this way jQuery will find faster the element you want to select (the selector in jQuery always has 2 parameters but the last one, the parent selector, is usually forgotten).

To select #citylist from inside the event you only have to reffer to the parent of the element who triggered the event ($(this))

Hope this helps

Comment: @downvoter any comments/feedback/opinions/arguments for the downvote?